# calculate encoder period from motor rpm?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, encoder

Let's say I have a stepper motor which rotate at a speed of 1000 RPM and I have an incremental encoder attached directly to the shaft with 4096 PPR (pulses per revolution).
How I can measure the period of the square wave of channel A or B of the encoder?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean by 'encoder period'? Do you need to add links to data sheets?

Comment: I mean channel A or channel B square wave period(or freq)

Comment: What's the encoder period? Anyway using stepper + encoder = waste of money, you can just detect that the motor has skipped steps.

Comment: Please clarify & make your question more specific.

Comment: There is no such thing, AB quadrature counter counts pulses up to max frequency, you have to write your own function to calculate frequency.

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear

Comment: @MarkoBuršič How I can detect skipped steps without encoder ?

Comment: Didn't you already answer your own question? 1000RPM * 1min / 60s ≈ 16.67Hz. 16.67Hz * 4096 = 68.28kHz encoder output. The period is about 14.7μs

Comment: @HisokaHunter In production line you have a person that can see the machine doesn't return at origin, you can have a photocell to check the return position, or you might use TMC223 sensorless stall detector IC.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thanks for TMC223 suggestion

Comment: @HisokaHunter There are also newer ICs, search stepper motor stall detection. https://www.pololu.com/product/2970

Comment: @MarkoBuršič still I have the problem of zero position , I have to find the zero position on power-on(its an embedded system)

Comment: Answer updated to include homing.

Comment: @HisokaHunter various possibilities, using a mech. limit switch, optical beam sensor, inductive sensor. This is called homing procedure.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič please see my answer down about the mech. limit switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulse frequency, f, is given by:

$$ f = motor~speed \cdot pulses/rev = \frac {1000}{60} \cdot 4096 = 68,267~Hz$$

(Divide by 60 to convert RPM to rev/s.)

$$Period = \frac {1}{f} = \frac {1}{68,267} = 14.6~us$$

---

**Homing routine**

From some of the OP comments it appears that you are using the encoder to detect home. The incremental encoder won't tell you where you are on power on. You'd need an absolute encoder or encoder battery backup for that.

The usual approach (e.g., in inkjet / dot-matrix printers) is to run a homing routine. e.g., run left at low speed until the home sensor turns on. (Allow mechanical over-run to allow motor/load to decelerate to a stop.) Then move at low speed to right until home sensor just turns off. Stop.
Now you just have to keep track of steps. The move-right step ensures that even if you power-up with the actuator left of the home position that it will always initialise to the same position.

An encoder can be used if there is a danger of stall and this needs to be detected. Alternatively you could re-home at every move left.

Comment: Thanks , but I think this is wrong. you must divide by 60 to convert minutes to seconds

Comment: @Hisoka Hunter  1000RPM * 1min / 60s ≈ 16.67Hz. 16.67Hz * 4096 = 68.28kHz encoder output. The period is about 14.7μs. but if you already knew how to calculate the answer, why did you ask?

Comment: @jms I was confused about something, but when I saw the posted equation I felt stupid to ask this simple question :(

Comment: Right-ho! In the back of my head I thought it was a very high encoder frequency. 60 s in a minute! That's fixed, thanks.

Comment: My system is a 2 direction 360 system , so there is no start or end point for a sensor like a mech. limit switch. so an incremental encoder with a z channel for zero position is enough.

Comment: Z-channel is fine provided you only care withing the 360°. Use my homing logic using the Z-channel and make sure you reference from the _edge_ of the mark and not just anywhere inside it if you want high consistency.

Comment: @HisokaHunter Why don't you expand the question about the real problem, describe your mechanical setup. As for Z pulse of encoder it might be too short, you need to have kind of limit switch, which could cover a sector. You start hi speed on search for sensor, then when detected you switch into a very low speed (you can reverse or continue) until the signal goes away, then you have a home position. You might need an internal counter for pulses and set the interrupt on signal transition to detect exact position.